# Extract Numbers out of a Column in Pandas DataFrame using pd.series.str.extractall vs. re.findall

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following column in a pandas df:

```
| Primary_key |
|-------------|
| LIT1-1.10_t |
| LIT1-1.20_t |
| LIT1-1.30_t |
| LIT4-1.99_t | 
| LIT4-1.88_t |  
| LIT4-1.77_t |
```

I want do extract the version number out of the 'Primary_key' (String); split it into a version_number and the the ID and put them into new columns to get the following output:

```
| Primary_key  | version_nr | ID |
|--------------|------------|----|
| LIT1-1.10_t  | 1          |10  |
| LIT1-1.20_t  | 1          |20  |
| LIT1-1.30_t  | 1          |30  |
| LIT4-1.999_t | 4          |999 |
| LIT4-1.888_t | 4          |888 |
| LIT4-1.777_t | 4          |777 |
```

I think `pandas.Series.str.extractall` could be the solution for my task, but i have problems to apply correctly. I tried 
`df['ID'] = df['Primary_Key'].str.extractall(r'(\d{3})').unstack().apply(','.join, 1)` to extract all the numbers into one single column ('ID') to seperate them in the next step. But with this code i only get the last three numbers:

```
| Primary_key  | ID |
|--------------|----|
| LIT1-1.10_t  |Nan |
| LIT1-1.20_t  |Nan |
| LIT1-1.30_t  |Nan |
| LIT4-1.999_t |999 |
| LIT4-1.888_t |888 |
| LIT4-1.777_t |777 |
```

Hopefully one of you experienced programmers has an idea how to solve this problem :)

PS: I also tried regular expression `re.findall('\d+',...)` but i think its not exactley the bee's knees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `str.extract` with named capturing groups should do it.

```
v = df.Primary_key.str.extract(r'(?P<version_nr>\d+).(?P<ID>\d+)_', expand=True)
```

To update `df`,

```
df = pd.concat([df, v], axis=1)
```

```
df
   Primary_key version_nr  ID
0  LIT1-1.10_t          1  10
1  LIT1-1.20_t          1  20
2  LIT1-1.30_t          1  30
3  LIT4-1.99_t          1  99
4  LIT4-1.88_t          1  88
5  LIT4-1.77_t          1  77
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Regex:**

**demo:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Primary_key" : ["LIT1-1.10_t", "LIT1-1.20_t", "LIT4-1.77_t"]})
df["version_nr"] = df["Primary_key"].str.extract(r"\-(\d+)")
df["ID"] = df["Primary_key"].str.extract(r"\.(\d+)", )
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   Primary_key version_nr  ID
0  LIT1-1.10_t          1  10
1  LIT1-1.20_t          1  20
2  LIT4-1.77_t          1  77
```